# Force align ionic view title to the center using css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to align ionic view to the center using css. This is my code

**CSS**

```
/*pull the title to the center*/
.pullCenter title{
text-align:center;
}
```

**IONIC HTML**

```
<ion-view class="pullCenter" title="Please Login">
```

This is the image result
[image]

But it never gets aligned to the center. Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.config`

**sample code:**

```
ionicApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center')
});
```

**OR**

Try adding `align-title="center"` in the **Markup**

like

```
<ion-view class="pullCenter" title="Please Login" align-title="center">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: By the [Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/) of `$ionicConfigProvider`. this only aligns the title center. try adding other contents with a different class.

Answer (score 0):

Change Target

```
.pullCenter{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.